# Deserialize Object in a different Assembly - Binary Formatter

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

**Background:**
I got the Source-Code of a Tool, that is used for many years. It has a Class (DB_Para), which get serialized by BinaryFormatter. Hundredes of File got created that way - So changing the the "saving"-process is not possible.
My Goal is, to import these Files into my Software.

My Attempt was to copy the class to my SW, but when I try to open the File i get this Error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "Die Assembly "FTF-Para, Version=1.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" could not be found."

What would be the best way to approach this?

**OLD Assembly Saving:**

```
 private void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.DefaultExt = "*.fpb";
        sfd.Filter = "FTF-Para-Datei (*.fpb) |*.fpb";
        sfd.Title = "Speichern unter";
        bool? res = sfd.ShowDialog();
        if (res == true)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this.DataContext);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

**OLD Assembly Class:**

```
[Serializable()]
public class DB_Para : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _Rack, _Slot;

    public int Rack
    {
        get { return _Rack; }
        set { _Rack = value; }
    }
    public int Slot
    {
        get { return _Slot; }
        set { _Slot = value; }
    }
    //Many more Attributes ...
}
```

Comment: _"So changing the the "saving"-process is not possible."_ - Are you _sure_ about that? I'd really recommend to write a tool that will bring those files into a reasonable format. The sooner, the better for you.

Comment: I am afraid, yes - The Software was used in my company for many years and there are so many files flying around in share-systems, local pcs, and even customers have some files. So using the original files directly is required

Comment: Did you try to use the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple` flag for deserialization?

Comment: I tried it just now - doesn't make any difference

Comment: I guess you'll need a legacy _runtime_ to read that. That's why I suggested to create a conversion-tool above. Include the runtime with it (pack as a single-file exe). And don't make the same mistake again.